# How to create ellipse shape in canvas?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm new to canvas. How can I create ellipse shape in canvas using fabricjs?

```
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas');

  canvas.add(
    new fabric.Rect({
      top: 100,
      left: 100,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      fill: '#f55'
    }),
    new fabric.Circle({
      top: 140,
      left: 230,
      radius: 75,
      fill: 'green',
      angle: 0
    }),
    //new fabric.Ellipse({ originX: 140, originY: 230, angle: 20, fill: 'green' }),
    new fabric.Triangle({
      top: 300,
      left: 210,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      fill: 'blue'
    })
  );

  fabric.Image.fromURL('../lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {
    canvas.add(img.set({
      left: 400,
      top: 350,
      angle: 30
    }).scale(0.25));
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the [Fabric Ellipse class](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Ellipse.html).

See below an example:

```js
ellip = new fabric.Ellipse({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  strokeWidth: 1,
  stroke: 'black',
  fill: 'white',
  selectable: true,
  originX: 'center', 
  originY: 'center',
  rx: 5,
  ry: 1
});

canvas.add(ellip);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of [fabric.Ellipse](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Ellipse.html) and use properties [rx:](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Ellipse.html#rx) for horizontal radius and [ry:](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Ellipse.html#ry) for vertical radius of ellipse.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var ellipse = new fabric.Ellipse({
  left: 20,
  top: 20,
  rx: 150,
  ry: 50,
  fill: 'yellow'
});
canvas.add(ellipse);
```

```css
canvas{
 border : 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```